# How to get rolling mean in grouped data?

Tags: python, pandas

My merged dataframe looks like below I want to calculate rolling mean of volume for each symbol :

```
df =

        Datetimes   Symbol    Volume      
   0    2020-04-15  20MICRONS   75893   
   0    2020-04-16  20MICRONS   87254   
   0    2020-04-17  20MICRONS   81116   
   0    2020-04-15  33MICRONS   75893   
   0    2020-04-16  33MICRONS   87254   
   0    2020-04-17  33MICRONS   81116
```

i want values as given in meanvol columns . i calculated on loop with symbols.
but its very time consuming.
below func will not work as symbols are different so what should i use?
i want to make column of Mean volume .

```
 df['Volume'].rolling(2).mean()
```

expected output:

```
df =
 

            Datetimes   Symbol    Volume      meanvol
       0    2020-04-15  20MICRONS   75893   NaN
       0    2020-04-16  20MICRONS   87254   81573.5
       0    2020-04-17  20MICRONS   81116   84185.0
       0    2020-04-15  33MICRONS   75893   NaN
       0    2020-04-16  33MICRONS   87254   81573.5
       0    2020-04-17  33MICRONS   81116   84185.0
```

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `groupby`:

```
>>> df.groupby('Symbol').rolling(2).agg({'Volume': 'mean'})

              Volume
Symbol
20MICRONS 0      NaN
          0  81573.5
          0  84185.0
33MICRONS 0      NaN
          0  81573.5
          0  84185.0
```

EDIT: Adding new column as per updated question

```
>>> df['mean_vlume']=df.groupby('Symbol').rolling(2).agg({'Volume': 'mean'}).reset_index(drop=True)
>>> df
    Datetimes     Symbol  Open   High    Low  Close  Volume  mean_vlume
0  2020-04-15  20MICRONS  26.6  31.40  25.60  27.85   75893         NaN
1  2020-04-16  20MICRONS  28.0  28.65  24.65  26.80   87254     81573.5
2  2020-04-17  20MICRONS  28.8  29.00  26.80  28.75   81116     84185.0
3  2020-04-15  33MICRONS  26.6  31.40  25.60  27.85   75893         NaN
4  2020-04-16  33MICRONS  28.0  28.65  24.65  26.80   87254     81573.5
5  2020-04-17  33MICRONS  28.8  29.00  26.80  28.75   81116     84185.0
```

Comment: its working. but is it fastest approch ?

Comment: Also how to make saperate column out of it??

Comment: I don't quite understand what is what you're looking to achieve. Can you please provide some `expected output` ?

Comment: i already updated question . I want a new column with rolling mean. as shown in question.